# Recorded VBA macro - run time error 1004 autofilter method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I recorded a simple macro to autofilter some pivot data columns by setting up the autofilter on the pivot header line.

Here is the code(highlighted where the apparent error is):

```
Sub Only_Choose_Unders()

' Only_Choose_Unders Macro

  Sheets("Lab UP no 360 Chem OPP").Select
  Range("K24").Select
  Selection.AutoFilter
  **ActiveSheet.Range("$B$24:$J$3296").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<0", _
    Operator:=xlAnd**
  ActiveSheet.Range("$B$24:$J$3296").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<0", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Many thanks everyone,
Eyal

Comment: You can't have `Operator:=xlAnd` with a single criterion.

Comment: Thanks @Warcupine, not sure what should I do then as when I erase Operator:=xlAnd** also doesn't work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Operator:=xlAnd` is for multi criteria autofilters (within the same field).

You want to leave the operator blank and it will filter on both fields.

I also removed the selections, they aren't necessary.

```
Sub Only_Choose_Unders()

' Only_Choose_Unders Macro

    With Sheets("Lab UP no 360 Chem OPP").Range("B24:J3296")
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<0"
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<0"
    End With
End Sub
```

As a heads-up the `Field` parameter is indexed relative to the range given. So `Field:=8` in this instance will be Column I, if that was supposed to be Column H you would want `Field:=7`

Comment: It worked when i changed the range to "k24:k3296" because I'm autofiltering an external column to the pivot table to be able to filter the pivot's data values :) many thanks

Comment: I'm trying to have different criteria if cell D2 points to Spanish territories vs. the rest but I'm getting a Run-time error:'13: Type Mismatch on the below: